# Identical queries in the DynamoDB console and using the node document client returning different results

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am running the following command using the DDB document client:

```
const queryCommand = new QueryCommand({
        TableName: TABLE_NAME,
        IndexName: "gsi1",
        KeyConditionExpression: `gsi1_pk = :type`,
        FilterExpression: `contains(customerName, :client) AND isLatest = :isLatestFlag`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":type": "report",
            ":client": "JACK SMITH",
            ":isLatestFlag": "true",
        },
    });
    const latest = await docClient.send(queryCommand);
```

When I run this command, I get exactly one Item back. However, there are TWO items in my database which should match this query. When I run the same command in the console:

[image: screenshot of DDB console]

it returns both Items.

I am at a loss as to how this is happening.

There is a further mystery: my database is initially populated with dummy data. When first loaded, the query in my application returns both Items. As soon as I perform an update on one of the items, the document client stops returning it from the above query. I have done a diff of the item before and after the update, and they are *identical*, except for changes to the fields `sk` and `gsi1_sk` (both update timestamps), which are unrelated to this query.

When I updated my query to use a filtered Scan command:

```
    const scanCommand = new ScanCommand({
        TableName: TABLE_NAME,
        FilterExpression: `contains(customerName, :client) AND isLatest = :isLatestFlag AND gsi1_pk = :type`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":type": "report",
            ":client": customerNameUppercase,
            ":isLatestFlag": "true",
        },
    });
```

(which, as far as I can tell, *should* return identical results to the above Query) I get both Items back as expected. I obviously don't want to use a Scan in production if I can help it. If it helps my DDB schema is:

```
{
                fields: {
                    pk: "string", // report uuid | advisor email
                    sk: "string",
                    gsi1_pk: "string",
                    gsi1_sk: "string",
                    isLatest: "string",
                },
                primaryIndex: {
                    partitionKey: "pk",
                    sortKey: "sk",
                },
                globalIndexes: {
                    gsi1: {
                        partitionKey: "gsi1_pk",
                        sortKey: "gsi1_sk",
                    },
                    isLatestIdx: {
                        partitionKey: "pk",
                        sortKey: "isLatest",
                    },
                },
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is very simple, you don't paginate the request. DynamoDB only returns 1MB of data per page, that's before you apply a filter which you include on your FilterExpression.

The reason you see the data in the console is because it implements pagination for you.

> DynamoDB paginates the results from Query operations. With pagination, the Query results are divided into "pages" of data that are 1 MB in size (or less). An application can process the first page of results, then the second page, and so on.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. Given "contains" is not a valid comparator for a KeyConditionExpression, are there any other patterns for achieving what I want to achieve? I.e. an efficient way to search by text in a sort key?

Comment: If you can use begins_with that would be the efficient way. Otherwise you'd have to use the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Each Query call processes at most 1MB of data before returning. When you have a filter as you do, the 1 MB is the amount of data processed before filtering. You need to page using LastEvaluatedKey to read additional pages.

The console, for your convenience, does paging automatically for you.

You have one matching item in the first page (1 MB) of data and the second matching item is in a later page. That explains the behavior you're seeing.

Change your code to do paging, and you'll get all matches.

Of course reading 1 MB of data for each matching item is pretty inefficient and shouldn't be done as a common thing or at scale.